# Windows 7 aero peek

Tags: windows-7, windows

Enable aero peek is not listed in the visual effects  of the system properties. In my registry I put aq zero in both Machine current user. check mark on task bar but won't un-check. Aero peek is about to drive me nuts. Can you help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please double-check that you're definitely talking about Aero Peek?  I ask this because there are a number of Aero features with similar silly names.  Aero Peek is when you move the mouse to the bottom-right of the screen and then all of the windows become transparent.  Is this the one you're having problems with?  If so, there are a few ways to remove it.

1. Move the mouse to the Aero Peek bit at the bottom-right of the screen, right-click it and untick the "Peek at Desktop".
2. Right click on the Start button at the bottom left of the screen,go to Properties, go to the Taskbar tab, then untick the box in "Preview desktop with Aero Peek"
3. You mentioned that you already put a 0 in both Machine and Current User.  Only Current User actually matters.  Can you double check that you put these in the right place:

   > HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

   The NAME needs to be "DisablePreviewDesktop" and the TYPE needs to be REG_DWORD.

If these things don't work, can you clarify a few things?

1) Which edition of Windows is this?  (e.g, Windows 7 Home Basic, Windows 7 Professional, etc).

2) Is this a work or a home computer?

3) Have you got any third party programs to "speed things up" on your computer?

If none of my questions above helped, it might be due to another program interfering with Aero.  Have you got any third-party desktop managers or desktop tools/toys?  Anything which interferes with your user interface is a prime suspect here.  In any case, you can try a Selective Startup procedure.  This is where you start the computer with as few programs and services running as possible.  If the problem you are experiencing disappears, you can be sure one of the programs you disabled was responsible for the behaviour.

If the problem does disappear, then you simply re-enable half of the programs to Start automatically, then try restarting the computer again.  If it's still gone, you know the responsible program was in the half that you *didn't* re-enable.  You might have to do a few restarts to narrow it down to a single program.

For a great Article from Apple (of all places!) on how to do a Selective Startup, check out
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2292 - though this mentions conflicts with QuickTime, it still applies to your issue.

Before changing settings in msconfig.exe, be sure to note down exactly what settings were in there so you can restore those settings later on!

I hope this helps.